# IValueConverter -- FileImageConverter -- Not Displaying Generic Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using a `FileToImageConverter` to display a image based on the file extension.

Everything works for normal extensions .xlsx, .doc, .docx, because I have a image for that extension in the Media folder, but if the filename has a extension that is not in the media folder of the project, then no image is being displayed.  I want to try and assign a generic image for all file extensions that do not have a extension in the folder.

So if the file was test.sql then assign something like file_extension_file.png as the generic icon. the normal icons are stored like file_extension_xlsx.png

Here is the original Converter

```
public class ConvertFileImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value as string == string.Empty) return null;
            string file_extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(value.ToString());
            file_extension = file_extension.Replace(".", "");
            var file = @"/Media/file_extension_" + file_extension + ".png";
            ImageSource src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative));
            return src;
        }    
     }
```

This is hitting the try still

```
if (value as string == string.Empty) 
    return null;

string file_extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(value.ToString());
file_extension = file_extension.Replace(".", "");
var file = @"/Media/file_extension_" + file_extension + ".png";
var genericfile = @"/Media/file_extension_file.png";

try
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(genericfile, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Updated: Here are some of the images etc.

[image]

This is setting everything to the default image with the !File exists even if the extension is in the folder.

```
private static ImageSource DefaultImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"/Media/file_extension_file.png", UriKind.Relative));

            public object Convert(object value, 
                                  Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                var filename = (string)value;

                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename))
                {
                    return DefaultImage;
                }

                var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename).Replace(".", string.Empty);

                var imageName = @"/Media/file_extension_" + extension + ".png";
                if (!File.Exists(imageName))
                {
                    return DefaultImage; 
                }
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative));        
            }
```

The filenames being passed in look like test.doc, test.docx, test.sql, test.xls etc.

locals are showing below:  the highlighted red is what it is looking for in the Media folder, but there is not one, so I am trying to show the Default Image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use File.Exists to check your file exists and if not return a default image.  Something like:

```
public class ConvertFileImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static ImageSource DefaultImage = new BitmapImage(
            new Uri(@"/Media/file_extension_file.png", UriKind.Relative));

    public object Convert(object value, 
                          Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var filename = (string)value;

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename))
        {
            return null; // or return a default image
        }

        var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename).Replace(".", string.Empty);

        var imageName = @"\Media\file_extension_" + extension + ".png";

        if(!File.Exists(imageName))
        {
            return DefaultImage;
        }

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(imageName, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again Phil, !File.Exists is making it return the dafault for every file now.  I think it is the way I am setting this line       var imageName = @"\Media\file_extension_" + extension + ".png";

Comment: You probably need a drive letter in there "c:\...".  and then your Uri may need to be UriKind.Absolute.

Comment: Thanks, checking, I added a image of some of the files

Comment: The filename is coming is as (eg. Test.docx, or test.xls, it just doesnt like test.sql)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [BitmapImage constructor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602473.aspx), you can see that it will throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the file specified by the *uriSource* parameter is not found.

Therefore, you should catch this exception and return your generic image.

E.g:

```
try
{
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException exception)
{
    // log exception etc.
    return new BitmapImage(new Uri(genericfile, UriKind.Relative));
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    // handle other exceptions
}
```